# Another Status: Tracking Not Installed, after deleting all views

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

All was working fine until I deleted all views and added my own one, now i'm getting the not installed message, www.securitytraining.club. all seems to be set-up correctly, have www.securitytraining.club set-up for both view and property, tried with and without www. Could it be that deleting all views means I have to wait 24 hours?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'ssl'; : 'www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: probably and you also deleted all of your data.

Comment: hope your right mate, getting tired of frankly hitting the refresh!

Comment: I tried another version of the code and now it says tracking installed but, I'm still not getting data also, if I take the code away completely it still says installed. I think I may have messed it up completely, may just go over to piwik

Comment: here the code i used: <script type="text/javascript">


  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);


  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();


</script>